# Facebook login button FBMXL not rendering links after appending

Tags: facebook

I have put a generic facebook login button on a site which has been working fine for the past couple of months. I open it up today, and it seems there is a problem with it appending links to the iframe.

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

Its a simple button as you can see, but I end up getting this in my code:

```
<span class="connect_widget_text">&lt;a href="http://www.facebook.com/fname.lname"     target="_blank"&gt;FName LName&lt;/a&gt; is using Application.</span>
```

You can see that facebook is populating the span element with html entities for greater then and lesser then symbols. :( for what ever reason.

Has anyone had this problem and have they found a solution to it? I don't want to write a lot of code for this I just want to place and forget.

Answer (score 0):

woke up this morning to the same issue: opening and closing tags after the connect_widget_text span are replaced with html entities.

Updated: same issue on Facebook's Developer Documentation page with an example of how to implement the fb:login-button plugin. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

Updated: Being tracked as bug at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19300